# Cant get data from a specific Table in MySQL to a Vb.net Combo box

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So here's my problem, I have a combo box that I want to fill with data from a table in MySql on load. I used this code for doing that:

```
 Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT containers FROM tbl_items_containers"
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, SQLConnection)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        SQLConnection.ConnectionString = ServerString

        cmd.Connection = SQLConnection

        da.Fill(ds, "tbl_items_containers")
        With cb_container_type
            .DataSource = ds.Tables("tbl_items_containers")
            .DisplayMember = "containers"
            .ValueMember = "containers"
            .SelectedIndex = 0

        End With
```

The error shown whenever i run it is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.

Now here's the thing, I tried getting data from another table in the same database and the code worked. My combo box was populated with data. I assumed that the problem is in the database, But I'm really lost here. I have no idea what to do. Any Ideas as to what may have cause the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` instead.

Comment: Run it in the debugger. What is the value of `.DataSource` after setting the property? What does it contain?

Comment: So the obvious question is what happens when you don't set the `SelectedIndex`? Do you see anything in the combobox? If your query returns data, you should see content in the combobox. If you don't, either the query doesn't return any rows or your code is wrong somewhere else. This is very basic troubleshooting that you should do before posting here.

Comment: oops, forgot to say that that is the error that shows whenever I run it in debugger.

Comment: i already tried removing that line, the combo box doesn't populate whenever I do that.

Comment: So now you know the problem isn't the `SelectedIndex`; it's the fact that you're not getting data. So check to see if your query actually returns data. If so, you know it's the code between the query and how the combobox is being populated; if not, the problem is in the query or data itself. Again, this is *basic troubleshooting* that you should have already done before posting here.

Comment: already tried the query and it returned data. Did that before posting this question actually.

Comment: I also already tried to change the query in the code to call another table and it worked, as I stated above. The problem seems to be the table itself, but I have no idea on what to do or what the problems seems to be.